# Numerical inverse Laplace

Tags: laplace-transform

I have this function
\begin{equation}
F(s) = \exp\left(a s + \frac{b}{s+\gamma}\right),
\end{equation}
for which I need to compute the inverse Laplace transform, at least numerically. I can compute the inverse Laplace transform for the Log of the function, namely:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\ln[F(s)]\right\} = a H(t) + b e^{-\gamma t},
\end{equation}
Is there any way to use this result to numerically compute $f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}$ over a finite interval $[0,T]$? I am using Matlab but so far the only algorithms I have found are extremely unstable and blow up at $t=0$. I should also point out that my time interval is quite small (T is of the order of $10^{-6}$ or so), so even some kind of asymptotic approximation would be useful.

Comment: CAS says:$\frac{\sqrt{b} \theta (a+t) e^{\gamma  (-(a+t))} I_1\left(2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{a+t}\right)}{\sqrt{a+t}}$ where: $I_1\left(2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{a+t}\right)$ and $\theta (a+t)$ is modified Bessel function of the first kind and  Heaviside theta function

Comment: Seems to work ok, which program did you use? I tried both Mathematica and Matlab but none of them could do it

Comment: Try in Mathematica: `Inactivate[
  InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[\[Alpha] s] Exp[\[Beta]/(\[Gamma] + s)],
    s, t]] == 
 Sum[InverseLaplaceTransform[
   Exp[\[Alpha] s]*(\[Beta]/(\[Gamma] + s))^j/j! // PowerExpand, s, 
   t], {j, 0, Infinity}]`. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all we are trying to find the inverse [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of:

$$\text{y}_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}\left(t\right):=\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\alpha\cdot\text{s}+\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\text{s}}\right)\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Now, we rewrite as follows:

$$\exp\left(\alpha\cdot\text{s}+\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\text{s}}\right)=\exp\left(\alpha\cdot\text{s}\right)\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\text{s}}\right)\tag2$$

Using the [time shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) property of the Laplace transform, we can write:

$$\text{y}_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}\left(t\right)=\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\alpha\cdot\text{s}\right)\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\text{s}}\right)\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\theta\left(t+\alpha\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\text{s}}\right)\right]_{\left(t+\alpha\right)}\tag3$$

Where $\theta\left(x\right)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Now, using the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) of the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function):

$$\exp\left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\text{s}}\right)=\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\text{s}}\right)^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}=\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\beta^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\gamma+\text{s}\right)^\text{k}}\tag4$$

So, we can rewrite equation $(3)$:

$$\text{y}_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}\left(t\right)=\theta\left(t+\alpha\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\beta^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\gamma+\text{s}\right)^\text{k}}\right]_{\left(t+\alpha\right)}=$$
$$\theta\left(t+\alpha\right)\cdot\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\beta^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\left(\gamma+\text{s}\right)^\text{k}}\right]_{\left(t+\alpha\right)}\tag5$$

Now, using the [table of selected Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms), we find that:

$$\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\left(\gamma+\text{s}\right)^\text{k}}\right]_{\left(t+\alpha\right)}=\frac{\exp\left(-\left(\alpha+t\right)\cdot\gamma\right)}{\left(\alpha+t\right)^{1-\text{k}}\cdot\Gamma\left(\text{k}\right)}\tag6$$

So, in the end we get:

$$\text{y}_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}\left(t\right)=\theta\left(t+\alpha\right)\cdot\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\beta^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{\exp\left(-\left(\alpha+t\right)\cdot\gamma\right)}{\left(\alpha+t\right)^{1-\text{k}}\cdot\Gamma\left(\text{k}\right)}=$$
$$\theta\left(t+\alpha\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\left(\alpha+t\right)\cdot\gamma\right)\cdot\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\frac{\beta^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\alpha+t\right)^{1-\text{k}}\cdot\Gamma\left(\text{k}\right)}\tag7$$

Comment: Nice! Thanks for that, is there a way to express that final infinite series in terms of known functions so I can compute it more easily?

Comment: $k = 0$ gives a delta function (the Bromwich integral of $F$ is divergent).

Answer (score 0):

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$. Then
$$\mathcal L^{-1}[s \mapsto e^{b/s}](t) =
\sqrt {\frac b t} \, I_1(2 \sqrt {b t}) H(t) + \delta(t), \\
\mathcal L^{-1}[s \mapsto e^{a s} F(s + \gamma)](t) =
e^{-\gamma (t + a)} \mathcal L^{-1}[F](t + a).$$
If $a > 0$, we need to take the two-sided transform to recover $F$.